# How to handle a method that might return null and generate a System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, oop, null, return, return-value

I have a method with the return type `Fruit`, that does the following:

```
Search for the right apple, if it matches return it; else
Search for the right banana, if it matches return it; else
Search for the right orange, if it matches return it; else
return null
```

Fruit is an interface that has the following:

```
bool Rotten { get; set; }
```

The problem is that when I try to use it:

```
store.GeTAFruit("magic apple").Rotten;
```

If it does not find the fruit it will return null, and that will give a `NullReferenceException`.

Of course I can surround it with a try catch but that means that every time I use this function I will have to surround it with try catch, that doesn't seem like a good idea at all.

I'm looking either for a solution to this problem, or rather what would be the best approach for this.

Comment: And now what you want to happen when call "store.GeTAFruit("magic apple").Rotten"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If GetAFruit can return null, then (and here's the technical bit): *check for null*:

```
var fruit = store.GetAFruit(...);
if(fruit != null) {
    //... Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, my problem is that even like that, I'm wondering what problems it might introduce in the future. The function will work most of the cases, so I'm afraid someone reusing it might use it without the if/try and see that "it works", but maybe it's a problem with no real solution other that document the function and warn the developers that use it.

Comment: @Trufa you could make the API more obvious, then; naming it `TryGetAFruit` might be sufficient. Having it throw an exception on failure (perhaps `KeyNotFoundException` or `ArgumentException`) would make it impossible to ignore - personally I'd be fine with returning `null` though

Answer (score 0):

this may help

```
if (store.GeTAFruit("magic apple")!=null) {
store.GeTAFruit("magic apple").Rotten;
}
```

*edit* to make it a tiny bit more efficient:

```
var fruit = store.GeTAFruit("magic apple");
if (fruit!=null)) {
    fruit.Rotten;
}
```

Comment: Really? Calling .Equals on something to see if it is null? That is really not a good move! In every case except Nullable-of-T, that is a guaranteed null reference exception if it is null

Comment: Why's that? I put the apple into a variable but didn't consider `.Equals()`

Comment: @DaveDev you shouldn't consider .Equals for this - **it won't work**

Comment: @MarcGravell thanx for correcting, you were right, its guaranteed null reference exception, editing it.

Comment: "a tiny bit more efficient"? You can't know how the GeTAFruit method performs, so the efficiency boost can be enormous.

Answer (score 0):

Simply check that `store.GeTAFruit("magic apple")` is not null:

```
   if (store.GeTAFruit("magic apple") != null) {

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches if you do not want to use exception handling. But the essence of them is the same. You must evaluate the lookup result to test it for null before using it.

The first option is to assign the result of your lookup to a variable and then test if before you use it.

```
Fruit fruit = store.GeTAFruit("magic apple");
if(fruit != null)
{
    //safely use your Rotten property
    bool lFlag = fruit.Rotten;
}
```

An alternative is to test it like so ...

```
if(store.GeTAFruit("magic apple") != null)
{
    store.GetTAFruit("magic apple").Rotten;
}
```

The benefits of the first approach is that you only perform the lookup once.

Answer (score 0):

Define a NullFruit : IFruit. Return a instance of it if nothing is found.